# There is an error when using URL Params in loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using a React-Router in my React project. I have a move page that looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

export async function loader({ params }) {
  const movieId = params.movieId;  // Fix the variable name here
  const movie = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/movies/' + movieId);
  return { movie };
}

function Singlemoviepage(props) {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>single movie page</h1>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Singlemoviepage
```

and my Router look like this:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Moviesroute />,
    errorElement: <Errorpage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "Movies",
        element: <Moviespage />


      },
      { path:"/",
       element:<Homepage />,
       loader: Homeloader

      },
      {
        path: 'Movies/:movieid',
        element: <Singlemoviepage />
      }
    ]
  },

]);
```

I am getting the following error when visiting  `"/movie/movieId"` route.

Comment: the post is missing the error

Comment: Please [edit] to include the actual *complete* error message and any accompanying error stacktrace, and clarify where the `Singlemoviepage` component's `loader` function is called, if that is related at all. The `Singlemoviepage` route's path is `"/Movies/:movieid"`, so the param you access should be `movieid`, not `movieId`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -3):

Quite some information is missing here , but I guess you want to display the data from your loader and therefore you should use "useLoaderData" hook.
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data

But I advice you to follow this tutorial first, otherwise you'll be clueless. Don't rush over it (beginner friendly)
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

The links provided are from React Router official documentation.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: *How* does this address the issues and concerns of the OP's post regarding an error they have? They are not asking how to load data or where to find documentation for it.

Comment: It's obvious that he won't get much help with the lack of details provided. 
It would be much more helpfull to him if he's pushed the right direction. The tutorial link covers the basics of routing with React Router.

Comment: "It's obvious that he won't get much help with the lack of details provided." - Then don't provide an answer that doesn't answer a question, leave a comment instead asking for the details. Dumping a link to docs and basically telling them to RTFM isn't considered helpful here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).